# My Android App is not opening from Facebook notification

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, facebook-sdk-3.0, deep-linking

I have develop an app, and it has a `facebook` integration which you can send invitation to your friends, MY problem is that the invitation I send won't open the App or the `playstore`, How Can i make it work like if someone send you a request from `candy crush`, once clicked that notification in your mobile app it will open `candy crush` if installed and it will open `playstore` if not installed.

[image]